# Ecto: How to Inject data on changeset, without Model.Callbacks

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Ecto.Model.Callbacks are now deprecated.

I am trying to achieve the same behavior as `before_insert` but to no avail! I can't even get anything to trigger `IO.puts("hello")` inside my `changeset/2`.

Here's what I have:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    IO.puts "HELLO" # never prints
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> put_change(:column_name, "hello")
end
```

Instead of `put_change`, I've tried subbing `change`, `cast`, and practically everything else inside Ecto.Changeset.

I've also tried the non-piping method, just in case:

```
chset = cast(model, params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
put_change(chset, :column_name, "hello")
```

The end-goal is shifting the row's `inserted_at` for a new value, so a simple `default: "hello"` on the Schema won't suffice.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you explicitly calling `YourModel.changeset` from your code?

Comment: have you tried adding a custom function in the changeset pipeline  that returns a changeset with your modifications applied on it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it via a Postgres fragment.

It's not quite what I was looking for, so I'll leave this question open for someone with an answer involving the `changset`, because that's still doing absolutely nothing for me.

Here's my *temporary* solution, involving the postgres Migration file.

```
create table(:stuffs) do
    add :expires_at, :datetime, default: fragment("now() + interval '60 days'")
end
```